# No puedo correr mi prueba unitaria en IntelliJ - Java SpringBoot

Tags: java

Process finished with exit code 255

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega en que consiste tu prueba, agrega el código como texto por favor y no veo que ahí trates de crear una prueba, por favor, revisa [ask] y agrega mayor información a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Te pido que añadas información sobre tu prueba. Añade el código como texto, no como imagen, ya que eso dificulta su replicación. Te recomiendo que revises las normas del foro para preguntar.